# Calculating the difference in sum() between different days in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query where I sum the values from a column WHERE the date = yesterday (current_date - 1):

```
SELECT sum(col) as sumCol
from `project.dataset.table`
where date = date_sub(current_date, interval 1 day)
```

What I want to achieve is to calculate the difference between the result of the above and the result of the same query for the day before i.e. where date = date_sub(current_date, interval 2 day)

I am not sure how to create this calculation within a query. I can union the above with the same query for the previous day, but obviously that gives me a row for each day rather than calculating sum(col) interval 1 day - interval 2 day?

Any help would be appreciated to point me in the right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when date = date_sub(current_date, interval 1 day) then col else - col end) as diff
from `project.dataset.table`
where date in ( date_sub(current_date, interval 1 day), date_sub(current_date, interval 2 day) )
```

EDIT:

More generally, you can get the two values using conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when date = date_sub(current_date, interval 1 day) then col  end) as yesterday,
       sum(case when date = date_sub(current_date, interval 2 day) then col  end) as day_before
from `project.dataset.table`
where date in ( date_sub(current_date, interval 1 day), date_sub(current_date, interval 2 day) )
```

You can then combine those columns how you want.  If a value is missing it will be `NULL`, so you are safe for division and missing values.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful. I have tried to use this to get % change but I get divide/0 error: SUM(CASE WHEN date = DATE_SUB(current_date, INTERVAL 1 day) THEN col ELSE - col END / Clicks * 100) AS diff,

Comment: @Arron . . . You need to specify what to do when one day has a value of 0.

Comment: Is it just one day, or is it any row? As I am aggregating up to date level

Comment: Thanks, edited query works perfectly and I can combine columns in calculations without errors.

Answer (score 0):

are you finding something like below

```
   SELECT
    ( sum(col) as sumCol
    from `project.dataset.table`
    where date = date_sub(current_date, interval 1 day)
     )-( sum(col) as sumCol
    from `project.dataset.table`
    where date = date_sub(current_date, interval 2 day)
     ) from project.dataset.table
```